# does not contain using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Below is the function that I am using in jquery

```
function addlnkfieldmkAndyr()
{
    var mymke =  $('h3:contains("Make")');
    var mymkeVal= $('h3:contains("Make")').closest("td").next();

    var myyr=  $('h3:contains("Year")');
    var myyrVal= $('h3:contains("Year")').closest("td").next();
}
```

The problem that is there is another field with the name as `MakeandYear` , so `mymkeVal` and `myyrVal` are getting the values from `MakeandYear` instead of just `Make`.

I would like to say

```
string.Contains("Make") && !string.Contains("MakeandYear).
```

How do I do that in jquery , please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Andrey pointed to the `.not` function, which is a perfectly good answer. You can also use the [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector, in combination with `:contains` ([live example](http://jsbin.com/avahat)):

```
var mymke =  $('h3:contains("Make"):not(:contains("MakeAndYear"))');
```

The advantage of `:not` (the selector) over `.not` (the function) is that you don't add unnecessary elements to the jQuery object and then remove them. Does it matter? Almost certainly not, and be careful making any performance assumptions, although I think your use of `:contains` means throwing `:not` in won't do any harm. You'd have to have a truly enormous number of `h3`s for it to matter either way.

Answer (score 6):

Use `.not` , like `$("div").not(":contains('Test')") ...`

See: http://jqapi.com/#p=not

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to end up with something like this.   (I'm not sure what it would look like if you tried to do the whole thing inside the string.)

```
var mymke = $('h3:contains("Make")').not(':contains("MakeandYear")');
var mymkeVal = mymke.closest("td").next();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can append `:not(contains("and"))` to your selectors. E.g.:

```
var mymke =  $('h3:contains("Make"):not(contains("and"))');
var mymkeVal= mymke.closest("td").next();
var myyr=  $('h3:contains("Year"):not(contains("and"))');
var myyrVal= myyr.closest("td").next();
```

But you should consider if there's a more exact way to identify the nodes you need than `contains()`. If you can control the output, you should mark the row with a class, or even include the `Val` in a `data-` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

How about `$('h3:contains("Make")').not(':contains("MakeAndYear")')`